# jQuery Datepicker on customizing year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have used datepicker from http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html and it was great.

But I have a problem on controlling the year range.

Here's my code.

```
$('#date_executed').datepick({ 
  dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy', 
  yearRange:'2011:2012',
  showOn: 'both',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: 'Calendar',
  buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif"
});
```

I need to add 2009 to the list of year but I don't want to include 2010. please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the year range to `yearRange:'2009:2012'` then remove the 2010 on load, like this:

```
$("select.datepick-month-year option[value$='2010']").remove();
```

Comment: I have done some sort of solution to remove 2010 for list 2009,2010,2011 and 2012

    $('#date_executed').click(function(){
    $(".datepick-new-year option").each(function() {
    var list_year = "2009,2011,2012";
    if(list_year != "")
    {
     var str = $(this).text();
     if(list_year.search(str) == -1)
     {
      $(this).hide();   
     }
    }
    });  
    }); 

It works but the problem is when I change the dropdown of the Month and Year, It loads the list of 2009,2010,2011,2012 set of year. please help me many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I change the Month and Year Dropdown the yearRange:'2009:2012 is again effected

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var yearRemoved = false;

$(".ui-datepicker").on("mouseenter", function() {

  if (!yearRemoved) {
    yearRemoved = true;          
    $("select.datepick-month-year option[value$='2010']").remove();
  }

});
```